# Are the [android] and [android-app] tags on meta synonymous, or one of them needs changing?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [android](/questions/tagged/android) which says:

> For questions about the Stack Exchange mobile site or app on the Android mobile platform

And [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) which says:

> This tag is to be used for the Official Stack Exchange application only. Currently the application is out in private alpha testing for Android 4.1 and up only. When posting bug reports, please specify the app's version.

Now I feel there's slightly too much overlapping than needed here, I don't know if a synonym is the best course of action, or perhaps changing the [android](/questions/tagged/android) to be less [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)ish.

Comment: Seems as if [android-app] refers to the Stack Exchange Android application, while [android] refers to the use of Stack Exchange on an Android device.  Similar, but not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different tags.

The [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag is for using the **mobile web version** of the site on an Android device browser, while the [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) tag is for the **official Android app** actively being developed.

I don't know why the "app" part got inserted into the description there, but I've remove it as it's incorrect.